# Sending a form through Javascript IE7 Problem

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I am using the following code to send a form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { document.form1.submit(); }
</script>
```

The code for the form is below:

```
<div id="donationWorldPay"><form id="form1" name="donation_form1" action="https://secure.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="post" target="_blank" >
<input type="hidden" name="instId" value="11111" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$amount.'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="'.$donationType.' Gift Aid ='.$giftAid.'" />
        </form></div>
```

Its works in FF, Safari, chrome and even IE8. But can't seem to get it working in IE7. The form sends to the right page in ie7 but no $_POST values are sent.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you show us how you create the form?

Comment: Do you have more than one form in the page? Is `form1` the **name** of the form? How are the values of the form elements populated?

Comment: Belwo is the actual form itself

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to:

```
document.forms["form1"].submit();
```

Assuming `form1` is the name of the form it should work.

If still no luck please answer the questions in my comment on your original question.